# Delete the Glance widget from home screen

Tags: android, android-appwidget, glance-appwidget

I would like delete my widget (Glance Jetpack) from the home screen, but unsuccesfull. My code is:

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

scope.launch {
  val glanceId =GlanceAppWidgetManager(context).getGlanceIds(ActionWidget::class.java)
                                    .last()
val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget = ActionWidget()
glanceAppWidget.onDelete(context, glanceId)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to remove a widget programatically. You are just manually calling the callback. The widget must be manually removed by the user unless the app removes the widget from the Android manifest.

You could set the `android:enabled=false` in your widget provider that should remove the widget once the app gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for Marcel! I fixed the issue by following his advice!
My code is:

```
val receiver = ComponentName(context, ActionWidgetReceiver::class.java)

val pm = context.packageManager

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
      receiver,
      PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
      PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

Comment: It's working fine in glance widget version alpha-05

Comment: In may case I have to edit the widget, so, I use COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED flag, late I use COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED flag it update the widget on the home screen.